# How to make div align into one line even though screen size is small

Tags: html, css, hugo

I know there are several questions that already answered but I couldn't apply them to my conditions properly.

I'd like to make some responsive 'information box' like this.
[image: example]

Since I use Hugo to make site, I made 'infobox.html' shortcode.

```html
{{- $type := cond .IsNamedParams (.Get "type") (.Get 0) -}}
<div class="infobox">
    <div class="infobox-inner">
        {{- with (eq $type "info") -}}
        <div class="infobox-icon-box">
            <div class="infobox-icon">
                {{- $fname := print "fontawesome/info-circle.svg" -}}
                {{- $path := "<path" -}}
                {{- $fill := "<path fill=\"currentColor\"" -}}
                {{ replace (readFile $fname) $path $fill | safeHTML }}
            </div>
        </div>
        {{ end }}
        {{- with (eq $type "warn") -}}
        <div class="infobox-icon-box">
            <div class="infobox-icon">
                {{- $fname := print "fontawesome/exclamation-triangle.svg" -}}
                {{- $path := "<path" -}}
                {{- $fill := "<path fill=\"currentColor\"" -}}
                {{ replace (readFile $fname) $path $fill | safeHTML }}
            </div>
        </div>
        {{ end }}
        {{- with (eq $type "stop") -}}
        <div class="infobox-icon-box">
            <div class="infobox-icon">
                {{- $fname := print "fontawesome/hand-paper.svg" -}}
                {{- $path := "<path" -}}
                {{- $fill := "<path fill=\"currentColor\"" -}}
                {{ replace (readFile $fname) $path $fill | safeHTML }}
            </div>
        </div>
        {{ end }}
        <div class="infobox-text">
            <p>{{ .Inner | markdownify }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, it directly embeds SVG codes directly into result HTML file. I believe it would be much more faster way than loading Font Awesome JS/CSS/Webfont in `<head>`.

With this structure above, I want to write some CSS stuff. It should do these:

> 1. Make round-rectangle around `infobox`
> 2. Align `infobox-icon-box` and `infobox-text` in one line, even though screen size is small.
>    I tried with `inline-block`, `inline-table` etc. but when I resize screen, `infobox-text` went down  under `infobox-icon-box`.
> 3. Resize `infobox-icon-box` according to screen size along with `@media (max-width)`
> 4. Align `infobox-icon` to middle(vertically) and center(of `infobox-icon-box`) and resize it.
> 5. Draw line between `infobox-icon-box` and `infobox-text` but not in full length.

I know how to do `1`, but I don't know how to do else especially `2`.

It would be much easier with `:before`, but I don't know how to use it with raw SVG.

Any help would be appreciated because after so many trial and error, my head went numb...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flexbox` CSS modal

```css
.infobox {
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.infobox-inner {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.infobox-icon-box, .infobox-text {
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.infobox-icon-box {
    width: auto;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.infobox-text {
    width: 100%;
    flex: 1 0 0%;
    border-left: 2px solid #000;
}

.infobox-icon {
    font-size: 3rem;
    color: #b35d5d;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

<div class="infobox">
    <div class="infobox-inner">
        <div class="infobox-icon-box">
            <div class="infobox-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="infobox-text">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium enim omnis veniam consequuntur ducimus atque ipsam exercitationem corporis quo rem dicta, corrupti nesciunt rerum recusandae doloremque voluptatum odit earum? Exercitationem?
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this worked like a charm, really appreciated! for SVG stuff, I used `width: 3rem;height: auto;`.

Comment: Add `width: 3rem;height: auto;` CSS declarations to `.infobox-icon svg` selector